# com.jniwrapper.win32.ie.Browser class is unable to render the agraphs and animation

Tags: java, swing, jniwrapper

I am using `com.jniwrapper.win32.ie.Browser` class for opening an URL in a `JFrame`. Url is opened but some report graphs are not rendered.

When I open the same URL in Internet Explorer, graphs are rendered properly. Please help me on this. Is there anything extra required to render graphs in swing components?

Answer (score 1):

This could be due to the version differences between the installed IE and the wrapper you're using. `com.jniwrapper.win32.ie.Browser` is wrapping WebBrowser control which is not the same as the full version of IE installed on your box.

By default, WebBrowser emulates IE7. This can be controlled with [FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730%28VS.85%29.aspx#browser_emulation) registry settings. Add your application name ie `AppName.exe` with value `9000 (0x2328)` under that registry key.

If you have control over the web application you're trying to render you can update it with the following meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
```

to enable IE9 features.

Also, you can try [Expression Web SuperPreview](http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/dd565874.aspx) to see side by side how a particular page/site gets rendered in various version of IE.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response.                                        IE 8 is installed on my machine and same has been set under registry FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION. IE is able to render the graphs while JExplorer is not. How is this happening??                                                         We dont have control over the web application we are trying to render.

Comment: @user1244613, did you add your application name under FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION? Try to set the value for IE8 - '8000 (0x1F40)'.